# Get Keys based on Keyword value in DWT

Tags: 2013-sp1, dwt, keyword

We are using Category and Keyword to display a drop down to author while putting content in component.

Now in TBB we can get value of selected keyword. But as per requirement We want to give userfriendly text in Value section of Keyword and someother text in Key section so that Author can select option based on Value and I can use key for development purpose.

How can we get Key based on the value of keyword in DWT TBB?

Answer (score 1):

Well, getting a key of a keyword (selected in a component field) in DWT is not straight forward. You would need to [create a custom function](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-81122EB9-655C-485C-B346-D5121AF0CA8C) to achieve this.

If your templating solution allow, I'd say to try Razor Mediator or C# TBB, where you get the field value as a Keyword object and you can get the key by using `keywordObject.Key`.

Alvin asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509454/how-should-i-get-keyword-key-from-dwt) and got some good answers. Please have a look, it could be useful to you.